# How to load AJAX content into current Colorbox window?

Tags: jquery, ajax, colorbox

I'm searching for the answer for three days in a row already. The matter is that I have a page, links on which should load Colorbox with AJAX content that in its turn contains links that should be loaded in the same Colorbox modal window. So far I managed to make it work (partially) by this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("a[rel='open_ajax']").live('click', function() {
            $.colorbox({
                href:$(this).attr('href')
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

It loads a Colorbox window, if I click on a link, but in this window, if I click on its links, it opens another Colorbox window. And I want the content to be loaded within the current one. Will appreciate any thoughts. Thanx!

P.S. Links in the main window:

```
<a title="Client Details" rel="open_ajax" href="http://localhost/client/details/123">Client Details...</a>
```

And links in the Colorbox are all the same (it is simply pagination):

```
<a rel="open_ajax" href="http://localhost/client/details/123/1">1</a>
<a rel="open_ajax" href="http://localhost/client/details/123/2">2</a>
<a rel="open_ajax" href="http://localhost/client/details/123/3">3</a>
<a rel="open_ajax" href="http://localhost/client/details/123/4">4</a>
<a rel="open_ajax" href="http://localhost/client/details/123/5">5</a>
```

Comment: does your ajax content also contain links with rel = 'open_ajax'

Comment: yes, of course, it works within Colorbox window content, BUT it opens every link in new Colorbox window (((

Comment: can you post an example of the content in your colorbox after it has loaded?

Comment: ok, I added the links in main window and in colorbox. No additional HTML or javascript is loaded

Comment: this might be stupid, but have you tried the `target="ajax"` attribute ? which means it could load it on a new window once, then reload on every other instance

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you need to load the content into the same Colorbox rather than opening a new instance,  I would start by making sure that the event handler context to open the Colorbox was exclusive and not hooked onto the 'open_ajax' elements in the Colorbox.

Something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("a[rel='open_ajax']:not(#colorbox a[rel='open_ajax'])").live('click', function() {
            $.colorbox({
                href:$(this).attr('href')
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

If the above does not work try making the selector more specific/unique.

Then AJAX in the new content directly into the Colorbox you already have open.

Something like this:

```
$('#cboxLoadedContent a[rel="open_ajax"]').live('click', function(e){
    // prevent default behaviour
    e.preventDefault();

    var url = $(this).attr('href'); 

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        dataType: 'html',
        cache: true,
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#cboxLoadedContent').empty();
            $('#cboxLoadingGraphic').show();
        },
        complete: function() {
            $('#cboxLoadingGraphic').hide();
        },
        success: function(data) {                  
            $('#cboxLoadedContent').append(data);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanx, it worked! Also I'd like to thank Jaitsu who also pointed to the right thing - somehow the popup included another colorbox instance, since small script was at the bottom of the page, and I didn't notice it.