# jQuery change content of colorbox

Tags: jquery-plugins, colorbox

I tried already questions with simliar titles, but they don't work.
(For example: [How to load AJAX content into current Colorbox window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273311/how-to-load-ajax-content-into-current-colorbox-window))

I have the main page: (including jQuery 1.6.1)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/colorbox.css" />
<script>
jQuery(function(){
    $("#aLink").colorbox();
    $('#blub a[rel="open_ajax"]').live('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr('href'); 
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url,
            dataType: 'html',
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function() {
                //$('#cboxContent').empty();
                $('#cboxLoadedContent').empty();
                $('#cboxLoadingGraphic').show();
            },
            complete: function() {
                $('#cboxLoadingGraphic').hide();
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $('#cboxLoadedContent').append(data);

            }
        });
    });
    });
</script>
<a href="1.html" id="aLink">colorbox open</a>
```

This works fine, the (simple) content of 1.html is loaded in the colorbox:

1.html:

```
<div id="blub">
    <a rel="open_ajax" href="2.html">Change Content</a>
</div>
```

Now I want to change the content by klicking on the link. This doesn't work.
Ether I get an additional colorbox, or nothing happens.

Thanx!

Comment: do you mean that when the colorbox opens (with content from 1.html), it has the link to 2.html?  So basically, you want a link inside the colorbox to change the contents of the colorbox.. is that correct?

Comment: the content of 1.html is loaded in the colorbox. the link "Change Content" is alread there. I klick the link... Now I want that the content of 2.html will be loaded in the existing colorbox

Answer (score 5):

You could use a jquery live() function to watch for clicks on existing and future colorbox links.  Also, I recommend that you don't use `rel` as your selector.  That attribute is intended for use in SEO. So in this example I've moved your selector from the rel attribute to the class attribute:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.open_ajax').live('click', function(){
        $.colorbox({
            open:true,
            href: this.href
            //plus any other interesting options    
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

Then just make sure that anything that you want to trigger the new colorbox content has the "open_ajax" class and an href.  E.G.:

`<a class="open_ajax" href="colorboxPage.html">Open</a>`

**Update for jQuery 1.7+**

For jQuery 1.7, since live() has been deprecated, you'll need to do it this way:

```
$(document).on("click", "a.open_ajax", function() {
    //everything that was in the live() callback above
});
```

Comment: Hi, this doesn't work. Now the content of 2.html is in a second colorbox (behind the first one)

Comment: Yes it does.. I'll update it with the complete code I used.  It doesn't open a new colorbox, but loads the content into it then resizes the existing colorbox.

Comment: I'm really sorry, but that's not a qestion I can answer in a quick comment and it also doesn't fit in with this answer.  And I have to go.  But it's a very good question. You should start a new question, and if no one has gotten to it before me, then I will give it some thought. PS - you edited your comment and removed your question before I finished, but really, you should ask it.  I'm sure it will be good search engine stuff.

Comment: Hi, the follow up is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7723062/follow-up-to-change-content-of-colorbox