# How to submit form and update colorbox without reloading page

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

this is a follow up to:
[jQuery change content of colorbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717848/jquery-change-content-of-colorbox)

Now the content of the initial colorbox (test_2.html) is a simple form:
For e.g.

```
<form id="foo" action="test_3.html">
    <imput type="submit" id="formInput" value="send form">
</form>
```

The form should be sent, and the content of test_3.html should be loaded into the same colorbox.

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer below as accepted if it resolved your issue (which it sounds like it did).

Answer (score 4):

If you add this to the docReady of your main page, it should take care of everything:

```
$('form').live('submit', function(e){
    var successHref = this.action,
        errorHref = "formError.php";

    e.preventDefault();
    $('#cboxLoadingGraphic').fadeIn();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "processForm.php",
        data: {someData: $("#someData").val()},
        success: function(response) {
            if(response=="ok") {
                console.log("response: "+response);
                $.colorbox({
                    open:true,
                    href: successHref   
                });
            } else {
                $.colorbox({
                    open:true,
                    href: errorHref
                });
            }
        },
        dataType: "html"
    });

    return false;
});
```

This code makes a few assumptions, though.  One of which is that this sends the data to "processForm.php" (as you can see), and expects the answer "ok" (in plain text, no json) when everything works out.  If you don't care about the response, or about dealing with errors, then you could just remove the `if-else` block and open colorbox with the page you set in `action`.  Anway, you'll probably want to tweak this, but it gives you an idea of how it can be done.