# How do I launch Colorbox for AJAX form submission in Drupal 7?

Tags: jquery, drupal, drupal-7, colorbox

I'm submitting a form using a call to this JavaScript function:

```
function emailFriend(){
  jQuery("form[name='comparisons']").attr("action", "/emailfriend/compare");
  jQuery("form[name='comparisons']").bind('submit', function() {
    jQuery.get(jQuery("form[name='comparisons']").attr("action"),
    jQuery("form[name='comparisons']").serialize(),
    function(data){                // send to colorbox
      $.colorbox({                 // this is where the error comes from
        html:   data,
        open:   true,
        iframe: true               // use iframe
      });
    },
    "html");
  });
  jQuery("form[name='comparisons']").submit();
}
```

This form opens another form located at /emailfriend/compare. The second form is the one that I am trying to popup in colorbox. The above code works to open the form, but it returns an error `$.colorbox is not a function` and then opens the target form in the same window/tab.

I am using Drupal 7 with the colorbox module installed and enabled. The colorbox aspect works throughout the site when using it for links, images, etc.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To avoid collisions with other libraries jQuery is no longer initialised with the `$` variable as of Drupal 7 (this is common practice in other system as well, not just Drupal). You need to provide a context for the `$` variable, or change `$.colorbox` to `jQuery.colorbox`:

```
(function($) {
  function emailFriend(){
    $("form[name='comparisons']").attr("action", "/emailfriend/compare");
    $("form[name='comparisons']").bind('submit', function() {
      $.get($("form[name='comparisons']").attr("action"),
      $("form[name='comparisons']").serialize(),
      function(data){                // send to colorbox
        $.colorbox({                 // this is where the error comes from
          html:   data,
          open:   true,
          iframe: true               // use iframe
        });
      },
      "html");
    });
    $("form[name='comparisons']").submit();
  }
})(jQuery);
```

or:

```
function emailFriend(){
  jQuery("form[name='comparisons']").attr("action", "/emailfriend/compare");
  jQuery("form[name='comparisons']").bind('submit', function() {
    jQuery.get(jQuery("form[name='comparisons']").attr("action"),
    jQuery("form[name='comparisons']").serialize(),
    function(data){                // send to colorbox
      jQuery.colorbox({                 // this is where the error comes from
        html:   data,
        open:   true,
        iframe: true               // use iframe
      });
    },
    "html");
  });
  jQuery("form[name='comparisons']").submit();
}
```

Personally I'd just use the second way as you already have that code written out :-)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Clive. Unfortunately, I'm still getting the error, only now it says `jQuery.colorbox` is not a function.

Comment: It sounds like colorbox isn't being loaded for that page, have you been to `admin/config/media/colorbox` and made sure your page path isn't in the 'Deactivate Colorbox on specific pages' text box?

Comment: I confirmed that it is being loaded for the page. I can add an image or a normal link to content that opens the colorbox just fine. I just can't post the form to the colorbox. Maybe it's a scope issue?

Comment: Yeah does sound like it must be a scope of issue of some sort, does the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273311/how-to-load-ajax-content-into-current-colorbox-window) help you at all?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I solved the problem by using a totally different approach that only just occurred to me. Instead of posting the results of the first form, I just built the URL from the serialized data and then used the colorbox to load that.

    $('#email-link').click(function (){
      $(this).attr('href', '/emailfriend/compare?'+$("#comparison-form").serialize());
    });

Comment: Glad to hear you got it sorted :-)